# No me muestra el valor de la variable entre páginas

Tags: php

En el registro.php guardo una variable con un string para que me muestre en el index.php que ya existe el usuario en la etiqueta p del final, pero no me muestra nada, soy consciente de que estoy utilizando variables locales entre distintas páginas, pero era para poner el ejemplo, también he probado con variables globales y nada, y la $_SESSION que sepa solo se puede utilizar cuando se hace un session_start(); para un login, pero no para un registro.

PD: del código registro.php solo he puesto la parte necesaria.

index.php

```
    <div id="dialog2" title="Register user" style="padding-top: 0;display: none;">
      <form name="registro" method="POST" action="registro.php">
        <fieldset class="display_block">
          <label for="nombre">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" autofocus class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="user">User</label>
          <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="confpassword">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="con_password" id="con_password" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <select id="tipo_usuario" name="tipo_usuario" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="0">Seleccione tipo de usuario...</option>
            <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
         <input name="registrar" type="button" value="Registrar" onClick="validar();">
         <p align="center" style="color: red;" ><?php echo $userExist; ?></p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```

registro.php

```
        if($rows > 0) {

        $userExist = "El usuario ya existe";
        header("Location: index.php");

        } else {

            $sqlPerson = "INSERT INTO personal (nombre) VALUES('$nombre')";
            $resultPerson=$mysqli->query($sqlPerson);
            $idPersona = $mysqli->insert_id;

            $sqlUsuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, id_personal, id_tipo) VALUES('$usuario','$password_hash','$idPersona', '$tipo_usuario')";
            $resultUsuario = $mysqli->query($sqlUsuario);
            header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] la $_SESSION que sepa solo se puede utilizar cuando se hace un session_start(); para un login, pero no para un registro.

Eso no es del todo correcto. Las variables de sesión se pueden utilizar para almacenar la información que quieras y poder transferirla de página a página, no están limitadas a la información del login en particular. De hecho, en el caso que presentas, lo más conveniente es usar variables de sesión.

¿Por qué no funciona lo que tienes?

En PHP, cada vez que se carga una página, las variables se "reinician" (con algunas excepciones) y todo empieza desde cero. Cuando en tu código haces `header("Location: index.php");`, estás redireccionando a otra página, y esa nueva página no tendrá acceso a la variable `$userExist` que asignaste justo antes.

¿Qué hacer para solucionarlo?

Usa alguno de los métodos para pasar variables de una página a otra. En este caso podrías `$userExist` como [variable de sesión](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["userExist"] = "El usuario ya existe";
header("Location: index.php");
```

O directamente en el GET cuando haces la redirección:

```
header("Location: index.php?userExist=El usuario ya existe");
```

Comment: Tenía entonces una definición incorrecta de la variable $_SESSION, te agradezco mucho tu respuesta, me funciona correctamente con ambos métodos, si me permites preguntarte, con el método del session_start(); noto que la web se ralentiza bastante, y con el GET por lo que tengo entendido no es muy recomendable utilizarlo por temas de sqlinjection, etc. Cuál me recomiendas en velocidad y seguridad ? Gracias !

Comment: @Cifu En este caso, con el GET el problema no sería de inyección SQL sino de XSS (porque no usas la variable para buscar en una base de datos, sino para escribirla como parte de la página). Tendrías que sanearla antes de escribirla por pantalla, por ejemplo con [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Sobre la velocidad, me imagino que la sesión ralentizaría algo, pero no sé por qué es algo tan marcado como dices

Comment: gracias caballero, le echaré un vistazo a esa función, pues desconocía que se podían sanear los GET :D